# How do I get a list of all Render Engine Options?

Tags: python, rendering, scripting

I want to get all the render engine options as a list but struggling to find the function for it, any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You gotta be more specific than that. What do you mean how do you get a list of all render engine opts? If you mean a list of available render engines than you did just that, there are no more render engines in blender

Comment: I want to get all the available render engine options as a list, via blenders api at the moment I can only get whatever one is currently active.

Comment: well you kinda have to say that we are talking about python api

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether I understand the question correctly. There is a lack of details. However, if your goal is to list the render engines using python and bpy library you can do it like this:

```
import bpy

for engine in bpy.types.RenderEngine.__subclasses__():
    print(engine.__name__)
```

but note it only lists render engines that are registred through python so it will give you HydraRenderEngine & Cycles. No specific internal names

There is however no way to list all the internal render engines, at least as far as I know