# Blender API : show list of available entries of a built-in enum property

Tags: python, api

This might be a noob question but I am trying to understand something regarding blender's api.

I was writing a script that part of it was to change the renderer to cycles, I was able to do that using `bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].render.engine = 'CYCLES'`

my question is:
is there a way to see all the other variables I can use (like 'BLENDER_EEVEE' or 'BLENDER_WORKBENCH') without using blender's info workspace?

e.g.
[image]

is it in the code itself or in the documentation? I can't seem to find it anywhere.

this might seems a bit silly for advanced users but I think it is a valid question.
Thanks.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58030/how-to-get-all-available-entries-of-an-enumproperty https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/154231/list-the-available-render-engines-with-python https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/308189/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-all-render-engine-options

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos: Your first link doesn't work in this case...

Comment: Indeed, seems to always just return EEVEE. Reopening

Answer (score 4):

An easy way:

[image]

If you assign something that does not match ("XXX"), you'll have the list of available values.

Answer (score 1):

To iterate on lemon's answer, here's an extremely hacky way to get the enum entries as strings :

```
import bpy

try:
    bpy.context.scene.render.engine = ""
except Exception as e:
    # TypeError: bpy_struct: item.attr = val: enum "" not found in ('BLENDER_EEVEE', 'BLENDER_WORKBENCH', 'CYCLES')
    # Parse the error, split the string and take every other result
    results = str(e).split("'")[1::2]
    print(results)
```

or as a function

```
import bpy


def enum_entries(data_name, data_prop_name):
    try:
        setattr(data_name, data_prop_name, "")
    except Exception as e:
        return str(e).split("'")[1::2]

print(enum_entries(bpy.context.scene.render, "engine"))
```

Comment: If luckily, "XXX" is not a possible value ;)

Comment: @lemon Haha yeah you found the one and only Achilles heel of this solution ><

Comment: That would be an awesome render engine name though. I wonder what it would be used for :p

Comment: replacing twitwitwitter

Comment: Haha thank you. You made me LOL in from of my screen at work. Now they know I'm browsing BSE x)